# How do I delete words that start with the keyword in the object value? javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

I have an array like this. I want to delete `row-?` words in `className` property.

```
[
  {
    type: "text",
    name: "text-1632646960432-0",
    satir: "1",
    className: "form-control col-lg-3 row-1"
  },
  {
    type: "text",
    name: "text-1632646974512-0",
    satir: "1",
    className: "form-control col-lg-6 row-8"
  }
]
```

I want a result like this.

```
[
  {
    type: "text",
    name: "text-1632646960432-0",
    satir: "1",
    className: "form-control col-lg-3"
  },
  {
    type: "text",
    name: "text-1632646974512-0",
    satir: "1",
    className: "form-control col-lg-6"
  }
]
```

How can I do that ? Also how can I trim so that there is no space at the end?

Answer (score 4):

**1)** You can [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) over the array and then [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) the `className`, [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) it and then [join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) it.

```js
const arr = [
  {
    type: "text",
    name: "text-1632646960432-0",
    satir: "1",
    className: "form-control col-lg-3 row-1",
  },
  {
    type: "text",
    name: "text-1632646974512-0",
    satir: "1",
    className: "form-control col-lg-6 row-8",
  },
];

const result = arr.map((o) => ({
  ...o,
  className: o.className
    .split(" ")
    .filter((s) => !s.startsWith("row"))
    .join(" "),
}));

console.log(result);
```

```css
/* This is not a part of answer. It is just to give the output fill height. So IGNORE IT */
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

**2)** You can also use regex `/\s*row-\d+/g`

[image]

```js
const arr = [{
    type: "text",
    name: "text-1632646960432-0",
    satir: "1",
    className: "form-control col-lg-3 row-1",
  },
  {
    type: "text",
    name: "text-1632646974512-0",
    satir: "1",
    className: "row-12 form-control row-6 col-lg-6 row-8",
  },
];

const result = arr.map((o) => ({
  ...o,
  className: o.className.replace(/\s*row-\d+/g, "").trim(),
}));

console.log(result);
```

```css
/* This is not a part of answer. It is just to give the output fill height. So IGNORE IT */
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

or `/\s*row-[^\s]+\s*/g`

[image]

```
const result = arr.map((o) => ({
  ...o,
  className: o.className.replace(/\s*row-[^\s]+\s*/g, " ").trim(),
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const data =[
  {
    type: "text",
    name: "text-1632646960432-0",
    satir: "1",
    className: "form-control col-lg-3 row-1"
  },
  {
    type: "text",
    name: "text-1632646974512-0",
    satir: "1",
    className: "form-control col-lg-6 row-8"
  }
];

const results = data.map((item) => {
  if (item.className.includes('row')) {
    return {
      ...item,
      className: item.className.replace(/row-[0-9]/, '').trim()
    }
  }
});

console.log(results);
```